# MYSQL ON DUPLICATE KEY insert something else

Tags: php, mysql, on-duplicate-key

I am aware of the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax in MYSQL but is there a way to insert something else instead? More specifically, say I have:

```
INSERT INTO main (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e');
```

where column "a" is unique and contains a random 10-digit alpha-numeric string which I use as a public query string in links sent in client emails to retrieve their data from the db. 
I know the odds are slim to ever generate the same string as there are 62^10 possibilities, but imagine that `$a` contains a 10-digit string that already exists. I have generated a second string in `$a2` as a backup and now I would like to amend the above insert statement that if `$a` already exists to use `$a2`. So ideally I am looking for something like:

```
INSERT INTO main (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e') ON DUPLICATE KEY USE $a2 INSTEAD OF $a;
```

How can this be done? As far as I know the `ON DUPLICATE KEY INSERT something else` syntax does not exist. Also my list of entries is about 20-25 key-value pairs long, so ideally I am looking for something that only inserts a different "a" without having to re-write the entire key-value pair list.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would do:

```
INSERT INTO main (a, b, c, d, e)
    VALUES ('$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = $a2;
```

EDIT:

If you want to add a new row, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO main (a, b, c, d, e)
    SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM main m WHERE x.a = m.a)
                 THEN $a2 ELSE x.a
            END) as a,
           b, c, d, e
    FROM (SELECT '$a' as a, '$b' as b, '$c' as c, '$d' as d, '$e' as e) x;
```

Comment: But does this not simply update column 'a' of an existing entry? I need to insert a completely new entry with a unique 'a'.

Comment: @Oliver . . . Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Wow that's complicated. Sorry I don't quite understand this syntax. Aren't there some keywords missing? E.g., `SELECT 1 FROM main m ` does not seem to make any sense (missing `as` perhaps?) Same for the `x` I think. Also what does the last line do? The `FROM (SELECT ...` ? Are you defining the variables as columns names?  Sorry for my ignorance ,,,

Answer (score 0):

You can also use REPLACE INTO. This replace the old data if primary key of your table matches else it will insert as new row.

Comment: sorry but this also replaces an existing entry. I need to inset a brand new entry, while ensuring that column "a" is unique.